# How to enable Network mapping?

Tags: group-policy, networking

In the Control Panel there is a Network Map which is disabled by default in domain joined computers. When I go to `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Network Map` I receive the message

> Network mapping is disabled by default on domain networks. Your network administrator can use Group Policy to enable mapping.

The computer is connected to a domain network.

How do I enable Network Mapping for Domain Networks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Technet Magazine article titled: [`Use Network Mapping on Domains and Public Networks`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee924643.aspx).

---

1. At a command prompt, type gpedit.msc to open the Local Group Policy Editor.(The Local Group Policy Editor is available on computers running the Professional, Enterprise, or Ultimate edition of Windows 7.These are also the only editions that can join a domain.)
2. Navigate to Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Network\Link-Layer Topology Discovery.
3. Double-click the Turn On Mapper I/O (LLTDIO) Driver policy.
4. Select Enabled, and then select Allow Operation While In Domain.
5. Click Next Setting.
6. Repeat the selections for the Turn On Responder (RSPNDR) Driver policy setting, and then click OK.

**Note that, depending on the size of the network, creating a network map on a domain-based network can be inordinately slow, which is why it is disabled by default.**

Also note that you can use these same policy settings to enable network mapping on a public network and, if you want, disable network mapping on a private network. For security and convenience, however, we don’t recommend either of these options.

---

(Emphasis added.)

The full description of the the policy option:

> This policy setting changes the operational behavior of the Mapper I/O network protocol driver.
>
> LLTDIO allows a computer to discover the topology of a network it's
> connected to. It also allows a computer to initiate Quality-of-Service
> requests such as bandwidth estimation and network health analysis.
>
> If you enable this policy setting, additional options are available to
> fine-tune your selection. You may choose the "Allow operation while in
> domain" option to allow LLTDIO to operate on a network interface
> that's connected to a managed network. On the other hand, if a network
> interface is connected to an unmanaged network, you may choose the
> "Allow operation while in public network" and "Prohibit operation
> while in private network" options instead.
>
> If you disable or do not configure this policy setting, the default
> behavior of LLTDIO will apply.